# Django Rest Framework TypeError a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have created a Rest Api with DRF. Everything works fine, but one resource (shoppingListItems) always throws this error:

**TypeError**

at /v1/shoppingListItems/

**a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'**

Request Method: GET

Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/v1/shoppingListItems/

Django Version: 2.2.7

Exception Type: TypeError

Exception Value:
a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

---

The problem only occurs, if one or more items are matched. If the resultset is empty there is no error.

Here's my views.py:

```
class ShoppingListViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = ShoppingList.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ShoppingListSerializer

class ItemViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Item.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ItemSerializer

class ShoppingListItemViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = ShoppingListItem.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ShoppingListItemSerializer
```

Here's my models.py:

```
class Item(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class ShoppingList(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    members = models.ManyToManyField(User, through='Membership')
    items = models.ManyToManyField(Item, through='ShoppingListItem')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class ShoppingListItem(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    shoppinglist = models.ForeignKey(ShoppingList, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    amount = models.IntegerField()
    price = models.FloatField(null=True)
    status = models.BinaryField()
```

Here's my serializers.py:

```
class ItemSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Item
        fields = ['id', 'name']

class ShoppingListSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = ShoppingList
        fields = ['id', 'name', 'members']

class ShoppingListItemSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = ShoppingListItem
        fields = ['id', 'shoppinglist', 'item', 'amount', 'price', 'status']
```

I don't know what's wrong and I would appreciate some help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because of the **status field (BinaryField)** in your **class ShoppingListItem**.

Try **changing it** to a **CharField**

Comment: That solved the problem. Thank you so much. I spent hours looking for this reason.